# Why does quantum computing only offer faster computational times for certain, specific types of problems?

Tags: speedup

Quantum computing has gained media attention about the exponential increase in computational speeds but only when dealing with specific problems which are prone to a quantum computational approach (such as cryptography)

Why does quantum computing only increase computational speeds for specific problems? Is this an inherent constraint with Quantum Computing or could we see Quantum Computing increase computational speeds “all around” in the future?

Thank you!

Ross

Comment: Hi Rostik002! Welcome to QCSE.  Your question is good, but it is similar to other questions asked here.  Have you reviewed [this other question and answers?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/is-there-any-general-statement-about-what-kinds-of-problems-can-be-solved-more-e)  If so, can you consider revising your question to emphasize areas for which you'd like further clarity/consideration?