# What problems can quantum computers solve right now which classical computers cannot solve?

Tags: ibm-quantum-devices, quantum-advantage

I know that an error-corrected quantum computer with unlimited amount of qubits can provide a significant speed up compared to classical computers for specific kind of problems, e.g. searching in an unordered list with Grover's algorithm or prime factorization with Shor's algorithm. Right now the largest quantum computer is IBM Osprey with 433 qubits. Are there already any real-world problems where the quantum supremacy is visible using for example IBM Osprey? I am grateful for every further reading source and links.

Comment: also related, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1584/55 and links therein

Comment: The two previous comments have great resources! For those looking for a TL;DR, the answer as of today is no. If it does happen anytime in the near future however, it will be big news and I think we'll be reading about it in the headlines.